# Histogram of labeled strings in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, octave

[image: Sample output]I have an array of containing some strings from a survey as results. I have to model them in an histogram and show how many times a value is chosen.

So far, what I did was to insert the data into the Octave. It is like following;

> airlines = {'Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Onur Air','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines', 'Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Pegasus Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Atlas Global','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Pegasus Airlines','Turkish Airlines', 'Anadolu Jet','Pegasus Airlines', 'Turkish Airlines', 'Onur Air', 'Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Pegasus Airlines', 'Turkish Airlines','Onur Air','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Lufthansa','Delta','Turkish Airlines','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines', 'Anadolu Jet','Onur Air','Atlas Global','Lufthansa','Turkish Airlines','Onur Air','Pegasus Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Pegasus Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines'};

I also created a label list which has all the airline firm names. It is also like following;

> labels={'Turkish Airlines','Onur Air','Anadolu Jet','Pegasus Airlines','Lufthansa','Atlas Global','Delta'};

I want to create the histogram like in the picture with the count of each occurence of each string in the array. So far I tried to use hist, histogram and set functions but they didn't work. Some functionalities from Matlab aren't supported here and to be honest I am struggling a lot. A little help would be great in advance. Thanks from now!

Comment: What did you try and what "didn't work" about it? See: [mcve]

Comment: For example, I tried to introduce the variables as nominal to plot them using boxplot but it didn't recognize the function by indicating the function is not included in the libraries. That was my attempt to solve the problem :)

Comment: Please post code and not an image of code. Also format code as code, at not as quote block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [uniq_c.m](https://github.com/octave-de/macgyver_utils/blob/master/uniq_c.m)

```
1;
function [val, cnt] = uniq_c (X)
  [val, ~, J] = unique (X);
  cnt = accumarray (J(:), 1);
  if (rows (J) == 1)
    cnt = cnt';
  endif
endfunction

airlines = {'Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Onur Air','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines', 'Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Pegasus Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Atlas Global','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Pegasus Airlines','Turkish Airlines', 'Anadolu Jet','Pegasus Airlines', 'Turkish Airlines', 'Onur Air', 'Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Pegasus Airlines', 'Turkish Airlines','Onur Air','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Lufthansa','Delta','Turkish Airlines','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines', 'Anadolu Jet','Onur Air','Atlas Global','Lufthansa','Turkish Airlines','Onur Air','Pegasus Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Pegasus Airlines','Turkish Airlines','Anadolu Jet','Turkish Airlines','Turkish Airlines'};

[labels, count] = uniq_c (airlines)
```

gives as answer:

```
labels = 
{
  [1,1] = Anadolu Jet
  [1,2] = Atlas Global
  [1,3] = Delta
  [1,4] = Lufthansa
  [1,5] = Onur Air
  [1,6] = Pegasus Airlines
  [1,7] = Turkish Airlines
}
count =

   11    2    1    2    5    6   29
```

finally plot it

```
bar (count)
set (gca, "xticklabel", labels)
```

gives:

[image: hist plot]

Comment: That works, however, instead of strings, I get numbers from 1 to 7 as labels. What can be wrong? Are you using octave as well?

Comment: Instead of `uniq_c` you can also use `[labels,~,id] = unique(airlines);
count = sum(bsxfun(@eq, id(:), 1:max(id)),1);`